# Is it okay to edit a question (on the main site) to downvote it after you initially upvoted it?

Tags: discussion, editing, down-votes, best-practices, up-votes

On the PSE main site (so not on this site), I normally never downvote a question or answer, but sometimes you change your thought about this (after upvoting). Is it okay to edit (when I wanted to downvote, the message was sent to me that I could do this only after editing the answer) just for the purpose of downvoting?

Comment: Why did this question get downvoted?

Comment: @Winston Downvotes on Meta are different than on the main site. Here they indicate disagreement with the idea that it is okay to edit a question to downvote it after you initially upvoted it

Comment: @BioPhysicist: thanks... but does that mean any binary (yes/no) question on meta get aye/nay votes? Is this standard practice?

Comment: @Winston If the question is proposing some type of action, yes.

Comment: @BioPhysicist: Is there a help section that clearly defines the meaning of votes in meta? This is not the first time I get confused.

Comment: @Winston https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta on this particular post the feature request tag isn't used, but I think same the voting attitude usually carries over in cases like this. At least for me that's how I voted on this particular question.

Answer (score 14):

Please use edits to substantially improve the posts they are attached to.

Please do not use trivial edits as backdoors to enable site features that are inaccessible to you for some reason.

Comment: What is the reason? For preventing a vote change for answers and not questions, that is.

Comment: @Winston, if I left you with the impression that I was suggesting different treatment for answers versus questions, that was not intentional.

Comment: My question is why cannot we change a vote to an answer but can when it comes to a question? What is the rationale?

Comment: After a vote is more than five minutes old, it can’t be changed unless the post has been edited. This is true for both question and answers. I just tested to confirm, but it took me a few tries to locate a question that hadn’t been edited after my vote.

Comment: Ah sorry I thought it was answers only, my mistake.