# Are downvotes (on the meta side) regarded as a (negative) answer to your question (on which you can answer yes or no)?

Tags: discussion, questions, down-votes

In [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13466/is-it-okay-to-edit-a-question-on-the-main-site-to-downvote-it-after-you-initia) question I asked whether it is a good thing to edit a question with the purpose of downvoting it. It got downvoted 7 times (up till now). This was written:

> Downvotes on Meta are different than on the main site. Here they indicate disagreement with the idea that it is okay to edit a question to downvote it after you initially upvoted it.

Is this the usual way to express an answer ("no" or "yes") to a question?

So, the question on its own isn't up- or downvoted? When user @annav is wished all the best, I can imagine upvoting.

To express it more tangible is the downvote right now (or are the ones to come) to be seen as a "no"?

Comment: On the question you link, BioPhysicist already linked the relevant part of the help center explaining that voting is different on meta in a follow-up comment. Can you be more specific what about that is unclear to you? Also, the title of your question is "Why" voting is different, but the body of your question seems to ask *whether* voting is different, this is confusing.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I didn't read that part though... I wasn't sure if just down-  or upvoting would constitute an answer. But now I know. Thanks.

Comment: In my experience, both on Physics SE and Physics Meta SE, up/downvoted can depend on the amount of research put into a question, whether it is on-topic, a duplicate etc. _In addition_, on Meta, votes can indicate (dis)agreement.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think that we should *not* use up/down-votes to indicate (dis)agreement on non-[feature-request](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) questions. The reason why is that if a lot of people down-vote a question because of disagreement, that would indicate that it is a useful question that should be addressed, while giving it the appearance of being low-quality or not useful. In other words, this makes it difficult to tell whether down-votes are because it's a bad question or because of disagreement with the OP. Instead, I think that we should vote to express (dis)agreement only with answers and [feature-requests](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-requests), while voting on non-[feature-request](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) questions in accordance with their quality and utility. To indicate (dis)agreement, one should write or up-vote an answer that expresses that.